# how to use unix find with parametrized argument?

Tags: shell, unix, find

```
echo $EXEC_DATE

20131002
```

Now, i m trying to exlude the files that has this date in their names.
I m running this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name '*{$EXEC_DATE}*' -print0
```

but no joy.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get `EXEC_DATE` substituted, you have to use `$EXEC_DATE` or `${EXEC_DATE}`, and you must not wrap it with single quotes, because no substitution happens within single quotes. See *Parameter Expansion* in http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash for more information.

Example fix:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name "*${EXEC_DATE}*" -print0
```